# Identify the initial landing page using reach router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reach-router

I'm trying to add a back cursor to my app. A back cursor should be on all pages except for the landing page.

The problem is that my app has two possible flows, so a user may enter the app from Landing page A, or Landing page B (depending on the flow).

Using reach router, is there a way to identify if a page is the first page a user has reached?

Comment: in 'back cursor' component use useLocation from react router and check if is 'landing page' path and just hide it when it is.

Comment: check ```window.location.pathname``` on component mount and render the back button accordigly

Answer (score 1):

I successfully used the `location.key` to check for this. The only downside is that router is keeping this state in a localStorage as well, so manual page reload will not show as `initial`. In my use case, this was not a concern.

```
import { useLocation } from '@reach/router';

const location = useLocation();

if(location.key === 'initial') {
    console.log('Initial page load');
}
```